# Font-face icons not displayed correctly after jdk and struts update

Tags: struts2, font-face, java-7

I recently upgrade the version of struts2 used by my project from 2.3.37 to 2.5.33 following the migration guide [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Struts+2.3+to+2.5+migration).
To do so, we had to update the jdk version 6 to 7.

Everything seemed to work fine until I noticed that some font icons were not correctly displayed anymore in some pages :

[image]

It looks like some Pe-icon-7-stroke font face is not correctly interpreted by the browser.
The css file containing this font-face is correctly loaded in browser sources but the rendering is not.

Strange thing is another font face icons present in the same css file are correctly displayed.

Does anyone have any idea why, at first sight, an update of struts2 could induce this regression ? Is there an element in struts.xml that need to be modified ?

Update struts2 version and test if the modifications did not cause any regressions.

Comment: What font icons do you mean? This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: Can you show how you use these fonts in your jsp